# Does WL.App.close() work on iOS?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

WL.App.close() works fine on my droid.  But does nothing on my 7.0 iOS iTouch.  Is there any way to force iOS  to exit the app?

Comment: BTW I have noticed you have asked several questions and received proper answers. If you could please set answered questions as Answered... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  WL.App.close is deprecated.  See [the note in the Infocenter:](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_closing_an_app.html)

> Note: According to iOS Human Interface Guidelines, an iOS app must not
>   contain an Exit button. The device's Home button is used for this
>   purpose instead. Apps that contain an Exit button are rejected upon
>   submission to the Apple App Store. On iOS, nothing happens upon
>   tapping a button that is implemented with this API method.